# Can't setq a variable inside a macro

Tags: elisp-macros

This is my first foray into emacs macros, so likely silly mistakes ahead: I'm trying to mimic the definition of `pop` (see the manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Elements.html#index-pop)), but I want to remove an element of `alist` indexed by `key`, returning the value corresponding to `key` from `alist` while altering `alist` in place. Here's my attempt:

```
  (defun alist-remove (alist key)
    (seq-filter
     (lambda (pair) (not (eq key (car pair))))
     alist))

  (defmacro alist-pop (alist key)
    `(prog1
         (cdr (assq ,key ,alist))
       (setq alist (alist-remove ,alist ,key))))
```

The function `alist-remove` works just fine. The macro `alist-pop` returns the value of the key correctly, but doesn't modify the value of `alist`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

```
-       (setq alist (alist-remove ,alist ,key))))
+       (setq ,alist (alist-remove ,alist ,key))))
```

Get into the habit of using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`.

Used following `(alist-pop a 'b)` it will show you:

```el
(prog1
    (cdr
     (assq 'b a))
  (setq alist
    (alist-remove a 'b)))
```

See also `pp-macroexpand-expression` as well as the functions described in <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Expansion`

Comment: One little comma. Thank you.

Comment: If the answer has successfully resolved the problem, please [accept](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it.